# Resample observations to achieve a specific correlation

Tags: r, correlation, simulation

I have a dataset of (people and their wealth) and (restaurants and their price). I want to resample this data (with replacement) such that there is a specific correlation between `wealth` and `price`. How would I go about doing that? Code below for clarity

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

n_people <- 100
n_resteraunts <- 100
desired_cor <- 0.5

# Generate people and wealth
people <- tibble(
  names = letters[1:n_people],
  wealth = rnorm(n=n_people)
)

# Generate resteraunts and price
resteraunts <- tibble(
  resteraunt = LETTERS[1:n_resteraunts],
  price = rnorm(n=n_resteraunts)
)

# Now I want to create a new dataframe that mixes people and resteraunts to achieve
# a correlation of  `desired_cor` between `price` and `wealth`
```

Comment: It may be more computationally efficient to look at integer programming algorithms rather than re-sampling with replacement. Out of a collection of points, you want to find how many of each will together produce a sample correlation as close as possible to your target correlation.

Comment: Genetic/evolutionary algorithms might be suitable. Even randomized hillclimbing or simulating annealing are likely to be more efficient than bootstrapping until you see a close match.

Comment: I am assuming that you have a fixed dataset, but your code suggests that you are simulating data. If you are using simulated data as coded above, then you should know that there are other approaches such as (1) sampling from the known population or (2) [Cholesky transformation](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/08/use-the-cholesky-transformation-to-correlate-and-uncorrelate-variables.html).

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance Cholesky looks promising; I can maybe do simulated data. But if I Cholesky transform price to have a certain correlation with wealth, is price still distributed N(0, 1)? Does it change the distribution?